# If statement in shell script - declarative pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I use following if statement within shell script declarative pipeline:

```
def currTaskDef = sh (
returnStdout: true,
script:  """
         #!/bin/bash
         RESULT=`(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${env.TASK_FAMILY} | egrep 'revision' | tr ',' ' ' | awk '{print \$2}') 2> /dev/null`
         if ( ! "\$RESULT" ) then
            echo 1
         else                                                                    
              aws ecs describe-task-definition  --task-definition ${env.TASK_FAMILY} \
                                              | egrep 'revision'                     \
                                              | tr ',' ' '                           \
                                              | awk '{print \$2}'
         fi
         """
).trim()
```

I am getting following Permission denied though:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/dev-test-local@tmp/durable-28ccc40c/script.sh: 4: /home/jenkins/workspace/dev-test-local@tmp/durable-28ccc40c/script.sh: : Permission denied
...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I use the bash if statement if doesn't work:

```
if [[ ! "\$RESULT" ]]; then
  echo 1 
else                                                                   
    aws ecs describe-task-definition  --task-definition ${env.TASK_FAMILY} \
                                    | egrep 'revision'                     \
                                    | tr ',' ' '                           \
                                    | awk '{print \$2}'                    \
fi
```

Output:

```
+ [[ !  ]]
/home/jenkins/workspace/dev-test-local@tmp/durable-d7af8721/script.sh: 4: /home/jenkins/workspace/dev-test-local@tmp/durable-d7af8721/script.sh: [[: not found
```

How to get rid of the Permission denied and why the bash if statement doesn't work?

Comment: `[[: not found` - it's not running bash. The ``(` is strange syntax, don't use backticks \`. Use `$( .. )`

Comment: I don't know jenkins, but two things stand out to me immediately: first, the shebang (`#!/whatever`) *must* be on the first line to work (and I don't know if it'll work even then in this context), so try putting it immediately after the `"""` instead of the next line. Second, `( )` doesn't do a test expression, it tries to execute its contents as a command in a subshell; `[[ ]]`, on the other hand, is bash-only syntax, and you're apparently not using bash. Use the standard single-bracket test syntax: `[ -z "\$RESULT" ]` (assuming escaping the `$` is correct).

Comment: KamilCuk still the same after removing the backticks. Gordon Davidson the single-bracket fix the issue as well as moving the shebang to 1st line after """ Now it works both ways. Thanks for help.

Comment: @patrykk : The `def currTaskDef = sh (` looks like you are asking to run the script by `sh`. I don't know the syntax of declarative Jenkins definitions, but would `def currTaskDef = bash (` work?

Comment: Pretty sure Jenkins just passes the script as an argument to `sh -c`, rather than writing it to a file and executing it.